# Prevent MDC Menu from closing after clicking first menu item

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-components, material-components-web, mdc-components

We are using MDC menu component. I am looking for a way to not close the menu when clicked on the first item in the menu.

I tried applying a class to mdc-list-item and specifying cursor as auto, but it is not working.

```
.menu-do-not-close {
   cursor: auto !important;
}
```

below is the example fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/phani25485/Lt6q2gxa/2/

Could you provide some direction on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can stop the menu from closing after a specific item is selected by calling `event.stopPropagation()` on the `mdc-list-item` click event when the event target has a specific class assigned. You will need to add some additional code to handle the list item click event since this prevents the normal [MDC menu](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-menu) click handling.

```js
const menu = mdc.menu.MDCMenu.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-menu'));
document.querySelector('.mdc-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.open = !menu.open;
});

//Prevent menu close when option with 'prevent-menu-close' class clicked
for (const option of document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-list-item')) {
  option.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const prevent = event.currentTarget.classList.contains('prevent-menu-close');
    if (prevent) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      // handle 'prevent-menu-close' list item click event
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Material Select</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdc-menu-surface--anchor">
      <button class="mdc-button">
        <span class="mdc-button__label">Open Menu</span>
      </button>
      <div class="mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface">
        <ul class="mdc-list" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-orientation="vertical" tabindex="-1">
          <li class="mdc-list-item prevent-menu-close" role="menuitem">
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Prevent Close</span>
          </li>
          <li class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem">
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Another Menu Item</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, clicking on the second item the menu should close. How could i achieve this.

Comment: Edited the answer and code snippet to enable you to apply a `prevent-menu-close` class to any list item where you want the menu to stay open after item selection. You could apply this class to the first list item and/or to any other list items in your menus.